# Как подключить отдельную процедуру на assemblere к проекту С++, используя dev-c++

Tags: c++, ассемблер, devc++

У меня задача подключить отдельную процедуру на ассемблере к коду с++. Я использую dev-c++ для написания. Есть пример задачи, который не работает у меня.

```
//Вызывающая программа file1.cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int MAS_FUNC (int *, int);
int main()
{
    int *mas,n,k;
    n=5;
    mas=new int[n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i=i+1)
    {
        mas[i]=i;
    }
    k = MAS_FUNC(mas,n);
}
```

```
;Вызываемая функция file2.asm
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
.CODE
MAS_FUNC PROC C mas:dword, n:dword
mov esi,mas
mov eax, [esi+4]
shl eax, 1
ret
MAS_FUNC ENDP
END
```

Я не совсем понимаю, как все должно работать, но я просто поместил .cpp и .asm в одну папку. (И это  наверняка неправильно, ведь в VS вроде как нужно подключать какой-то masm и т.д.) При запуске .cpp выдает такую ошибку **...undefined reference to `MAS_FUNC**. Гайдов я не нашел по dev-c++ и поэтому пишу тут, как сделать так, чтобы заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Ох, ну смотри. Тут несколько шагов, которые нужно выполнить, чтобы подключить ассемблерный код к C++ в Dev-C++:

1. Компиляция вашего ассемблерного кода в объектный файл.
2. Линковка этого объектного файла с вашим C++ кодом.

В Dev-C++ используй интегрированный компилятор GNU (GCC), который поддерживает ассемблерный код на языке AT&T (не на Intel). Это означает, что надо преобразовать  ассемблерный код в формат AT&T, если хочешь его скомпилировать с помощью GCC.

Однако, если хочешь использовать ассемблерный код в формате Intel, то надо использовать ассемблер NASM, который можно установить отдельно.

Код на ассемблере должен выглядеть примерно так для NASM:

```
section .text
global MAS_FUNC
MAS_FUNC:
    mov esi, [esp+4]
    mov eax, [esi+4]
    shl eax, 1
    ret
```

Чтобы скомпилировать ассемблерный код в объектный файл, выполни следующую команду в командной строке:

```
nasm -f win32 file2.asm
```

Это создаст файл `file2.obj`. Затем скомпилируй C++ код и связать его с `file2.obj`:

```
g++ file1.cpp file2.obj -o output
```

Это создаст исполняемый файл `output.exe`, который уже можно запустить.

И тут важно, эти команды предназначены для выполнения в командной строке, а не внутри среды Dev-C++. На данный момент я не знаю, как можно настроить Dev-C++ для работы с NASM напрямую.

Прежде чем продолжить, убедитесь, что установлены NASM и GCC, и что они доступны из командной строки (т.е. они находятся в вашем PATH).

Comment: Я сделал всё, как вы и сказали. Установил NASM, понял как использовать через командную строку и NASM, и gcc. Создал .obj моей процедуры. Но связать .cpp с .obj не могу. Ошибка вот такая:

_C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386 architecture of input file `file.obj' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status_

Comment: Проверь что если версия NASM для 32-битной архитектуры, а Dev-C++ использует компилятор GCC для 64-битной архитектуры.

Comment: В dev-c++ можно работать как и с 32 битной, так и 64. Я, к сожалению, не знаю, как в этой области что-то поменять. Но я изменил твою команду на "nasm -f win64 file2.asm", после этого с помощью g++ связал .obj с .cpp, появился output.exe. Но его запуск ничего не дает (я вроде добавил в .cpp вывод значения, т.е. результат бы был). А запуск .cpp с помощью g++ и консоли командой "g++ filec.cpp -o outputfile" дает ошибку "undefined reference to `MAS_FUNC'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status".
Код ассемблера тут дурной, но я думаю, препод оценит старания. Ибо сам хуй, а не инфу дал.